# sql server glassfish eclipselink jpa issue

Tags: java, jpa, sql-server-2014, netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

I am creating a simple online form using netbeans 8.2, sql server 2014, glassfish 4.1.1 (embedded) and sqljdbc4-2.0.jar. So, once I create the controller..

package controller;

```
import entity.KkkkkkkFacade;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named(value = "controller")
@RequestScoped
public class Controller {

    @EJB
    private KkkkkkkFacade kkkkkkkFacade;
    @Inject
private Kkkkkkk kkkkkkk;


}
```

I get the error..

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [MyOps]
    Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
    org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.getNormalizedPropertyName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/logging/Logger;)Ljava/lang/String; from class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Util
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:815)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:398)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:487)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [MyOps] : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.getNormalizedPropertyName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/logging/Logger;)Ljava/lang/String; from class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Util
    Warning:
```

I use the same way to connect with mysql and oracle!
please help me in identifying my issue

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue..it seems there is a bug in 4.1 + glassfish version that prevents the deployment of SQL server applications.

I added glassfish v.4 to netbeans, moved the project to it, then project ran successfully.